# Images overflowing their border

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, border

i am working on an image hosting website, and for some reason the images in the gallery overflow their maximum width border

```
max-width: 495px;
```

full CSS:

```
    .imagebox{
border: 1px solid gray;
height: 495px;
width: 495px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 495px;
}
.image_container img {
vertical-align: middle;
max-width: 495px;
}
```

screenshot of how the overflowing images look:
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]
[image]
Also, anyone has any tip on how to remove those annoyimg default image borders?
Thank you for taking the time on reading my post, any help will be gladly appriciated.

Comment: have you tried `overflow:hidden;` ?

Comment: No actually, ill try it now, but where do i put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reducing the max-width slightly to see what happens? (Maybe to 485px)
For removing the borders, I am not sure how many images you are working with but you could always go the old-fashioned route - open it up in an image editing program and downsize it from there :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove image border in css `img {border:none, outline: none;}`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the picture's border. The picture's width is 495px, as you set, but it's right border goes over the max-width and the left border pushes the image even more to the right. If the border is 1px, make the pic's width to 493px.

About how to remove them, I don't understand your question because you set the border to "1px solid gray". try setting "border:0;".

Comment: The 1px solid gray is the image box itself, i meant the border when you put an img tag it also puts a default border